# scala -object sql is not a member of package org.apache.spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

When i am trying to build maven project in eclipse IDE based on scala nature.

**Getting error**

object sql is not a member of package org.apache.spark

**We tried**

Adding this dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Input code**

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext



object MyApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    //Read from KAFKA TOPIC 
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Spark-Kafk-Integration")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
    val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "hostname:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("test4" -> 1))
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

 kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
 rdd.foreach(println)

 if(rdd.count()>0) {
// rdd.toDF("value").coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).text("file:///D:/my/")
// rdd.toDF("value").coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).text("file://user/cloudera/testdata")

 rdd.toDF("value").coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).text("hdfs://hostname:8020/user/cloudera/testdata")

 // rdd.saveAsTextFile("C:/data/spark/")
 }
 })
```

**Complete POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cyb</groupId>
    <artifactId>First</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>First</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Output**

We want to write the stream data into HDFS storage from Kafka topic.

Any help on it would be much appreciated ?

Comment: What are other dependencies with versions that you used?

Comment: When you have added the dependency `spark-sql_2.11`, have you tried `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: Yes i did mvn clean install after putting the dependency

Comment: I used following dependency version : <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: can you see the jar file for spark sql in the extra libraries ?

Comment: Yes i can see that

Comment: What are the spark core version, can you paste some more error ?

Comment: Pasted complete pom.xml  in question.

Comment: Name spark-core_2.11-1.6.0.jar i can see this jar included at build path

Comment: object sql is not a member of package org.apache.spark  only this much  is showing

Answer (score 1):

You need to import spark sql libraries to use spark-sql functions. Try importing this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
```